# {comment_total} Counts Remain After Deleting Comments

Tags: upgrade, comments

I just updated a site from EE1 to EE2 that had pretty much nothing but spam comments. I deleted all the comments with a query:

```
DELETE FROM exp_comments WHERE status = 'o';
```

But on the blog listing page, the `{comment_total}` tag is still showing that comments exist. For example:

```
<a href="{path='blog/post'}">{comment_total} Comment(s) &raquo;</a>
```

Returns

> 4 Comments »

Even though there are no comments in the database for that entry.

I also went into the `exp_channels` table and set the `total_comments` column to 0 for the blog channel.

When I upgraded from EE1 to 2, I opted to convert trackbacks to comments, could that be what's causing the phantom comments? There's no `exp_trackbacks` table anymore, so I'm not sure where they might be hiding.

I guess ultimately what I need to know is where does EE get its `comment_total` count from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried CP > Tools > Data > Recount Statistics?

Comment: That did it, thanks! I have never used that tool before now.

Answer (score 2):

Total comments are actually stored in the `exp_channel_titles` data table, so you would either need to use the `Recount Statistics` Tool, as @Ryan Masuga suggested or set the `comment_total` field in `exp_channel_titles` equal to zero, using a MySQL query. The **Recount Statistics** tool is the easiest method, unless you don't want all comment numbers to be reset.

Comment: Good info, thanks! Ryan got there first so he got the accept, but thank you for answering!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the page is cached so it's worth [**clearing the cache**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/tools/data/clear_cached_data_files.html) to eliminate that as the issue.

**CP Location:** Tools ‣ Data ‣ Clear Caching

Comment: I already tried that with no success, but it's always a good suggestion, thanks!